# Create Tweet API not working for other users

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've created a Twitter developer account with my profile and passing cosumer_key, consumer_secret, token_id, and token_secret and If I'm hitting create-tweet `'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'` API then I'm getting a proper response but if I'm creating tweets with other users credentials I'm getting an error
`([errors]=> Array([code] => 32, [message] => Could not authenticate you.))`. I've given read & write permission to my app as well.

```
    public function createTweet(Request $req) {
    Log::channel('twitterwebhook')->info($req->all());

    $access_token = $req->require('token_id');
    $acess_token_secret = $req->require('token_secret');
    $message = $req->require('message');
    $twitter = new TwitterAPI($access_token, $acess_token_secret);

    $response = $twitter->createTweet($message);
    
    if(isset($response->errors)){
        return error($response->errors, 4099);
    }
    $data = [
        'tweet_id'=> $response->id,
        'tweet_str_id' =>$response->id_str,
        'message' =>$response->text,
        'user_twitter_id'=>$response->user->id,
        'user_twitter_name'=>$response->user->name,
        'user_twitter_screen_name'=>$response->user->screen_name
    ];
    return success($data);
}

public function createTweet($tweet_message) {
    $postfields = [
        'status' => $tweet_message, 
        'trim_user' => false
    ];

    $twitterResponse =  $this->buildOauth($this->_update_url, 'POST')
                             ->setPostfields($postfields)
                             ->performRequest();
    return json_decode($twitterResponse);

}
```

Comment: _"with other users credentials"_ means what, exactly?

Comment: @CBroe It means I'm testing my app with another Twitter user credential like token_id, token_secret. So I should not get this error.

Comment: What library/SDK are you using there?

Comment: Have you changed the application permissions (adding write) since the access tokens for the other users were generated? If so, they will need to sign in again, to get the write permission.

Comment: @AndyPiper I've given permission read and write while creating the app.

Comment: @CBroe I'm using twitter-api-php library.